# OwlCarousel in not working when I get data from MVC controller using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net

In my [`plnkr`](http://plnkr.co/edit/0H43cyDXdlUwfnxuNUNO?p=preview) OwlCarousel is working perfectly.

But **when I get data from my MVC controller on that time OwlCarousel not showing desired result.**

In my MVC controller(*TestController*) have a method "*GetJsonResult*" which is given into my [`plnkr`](http://plnkr.co/edit/0H43cyDXdlUwfnxuNUNO?p=info) in the name of "**MVCController**".

I took data from my MVC controller(TestController)  using angularJS HTTP get request. That code also given into the [`plnkr`](http://plnkr.co/edit/0H43cyDXdlUwfnxuNUNO?p=info) in the name of "**UsingAngularJS_App**"

***After took that data into my angularJS controller, I send it to OwlCarousel  in same way but I can't get my desired output.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete :: from(::mySubject)` your second ng-repeat

```
<data-owl-carousel 
class="owl-carousel" 
data-options="{navigation: false, pagination: true, rewindNav : false}">

            <div owl-carousel-item="" ng-repeat="item in **mySubject**" class="item">
                <p>{{::item}}</p>
            </div>
        </data-owl-carousel>
```

Comment: **thanks bro for your help.**
I got another solution with some customize option.
Link is here : [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-repeat-owl-carousel)